# How to open another Activity as a logical dialog and resume the parent activity when it's finished?

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a general help for all of our companies Android applications and it should work like this:

- User is in Activity/Fragment A
- There is a help icon anywhere on the screen
- On its explicit click, or during a user interaction flow, Activity/Fragment A freezes, and initiates Help fragment, passing a key only to the Help fragment, so that Help can retrieve data from server and display it in whatever format it wants
- At the end of Help, user clicks a button.
- Help activity should be closed
- Activity/Fragment A should become alive, but not from the beginning, from the last state it had, preferably, from the last line of code it was executing.

In fact I can say that I need a full-screen dialog (web or Windows terminology)

I've seen other questions, which explain about `singleTask` and `singleInstance` activities. However, the problem is that the Help activity knows nothing about the parent/initiator activity. Thus I don't want to use `Intent`. I tried using `finish` without starting an intent. However, by just finishing the Help activity, Activity/Fragment A doesn't get `onNewIntent` and won't be notified to resume code execution.

I'm stock at this point. What should I do? We have successfully implemented this architecture in Winodows and Web platforms, and we're pretty content with this design. Yet I would appreciate any design tips in Android world too.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `DialogFragment`, check a tutorial here [codepath/DialogFragment](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-DialogFragment)

Comment: Can it be shown just like ordinary activities, to cover everything beneath?

Comment: @SaeedNeamati they behave like a Fragment, but you can show them on top of any place and will show it like that, handling close on click outside and those kind of things.

Comment: What you mentioned might be used in YouTube's filtering pane. That's not what OP mentioned. The full-screen thing.

Comment: @SaeedNeamati it is confusing, then why not an activity if its a full screen thing?

Comment: actually that's what we do. The only reason we asked this question is how make that dialog activity agnostic of its parent. Because it can be called from any activity, and it should go back to that same activity.

Comment: @SaeedNeamati Still dont get what you mean by "agnostic of its parent", you want to use some kind of Listener or something? you need to use what the platform offers to you, sometimes you need to use those mechanisms instead of trying to apply what you use in other technologies here or its really possible that you will end up doing something really ugly

Answer (score 0):

Please explain what you mean by "don't want to use intent".

Have you tried starting the HelpActivity using startActivityForResult?
It provides a onActivityResult callback to the activity that made the call to it.

Comment: This is a comment at best; certainly not an answer.

Comment: I am not getting an Add Comment option for the original post